# Chebyshev like inequalities for the number of prime powers up to $ x $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Denoting by  $ \Pi_{k}(x) $ the number of integers of the form  $ p^{k} $ up to  $ x $ where  $ p $ is a prime, are there known inequalities similar to Chebyshev's ones for  $ \Pi_{k}(x) $, namely of the form  $ A_{k}\frac{x^{c_{k}}}{\log^{d_{k}}x}<\Pi_{k}(x)<B_{k}\frac{x^{c_{k}}}{\log^{d_{k}}x} $ for all  $ x>x_{k} $, with explicit values of the considered constants depending only on $ k $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly if $p^k < x$ then $p < x^{1/k}$ hence the number of prime powers $p^k$ less than a given number $x$ is equal to the number of primes $\le x^{1/k}$. This gives

$$
\Pi_k(x) = \pi(x^{1/k})
$$

With this formulation, you can now use all the known upper and lower bounds on the prime counting function ([such as the ones given by Dusart](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442.pdf)) to estimate $\Pi_k(x)$.